# managing multiple shared projects to publish?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010

here is my scenario. I have 3 website projects doing similar job and those websites are using shared class library projects as BSL(business layer) and DAL(database layer). therefore different part is only on website project. if I make a change in the shared projects,  I have to do publish/upload for each websites on my web server. I have also a web service providing content of these websites. basically using the shared classes libraries of websites and returning as soap output.

Now my question is how can I centralize my shared class libraries projects that It requires only 1 publish and websites to take changes?

It sounds like a webservice is the way to go. but I don't like the performance of webservice. I believe it will be slower if I use a webservice.

Comment: If you mean "ASMX web service" when you say "webservice" then you're right about it being slow. If you use WCF with net.tcp binding or maybe even named pipes binding, then it may be fast enough for you.

Comment: Yes, I mean asmx web services. I was also thinking about wcf tcp net binding but I have never used it and I don't know how fast is it in intranet. Should be fast enough I believe. I just wanted to know if there are better approaches to consider. Thanks

Comment: WCF is always a better approach than ASMX. Also, if the two ends are on the same machine, then the named pipes bindings should be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy the assemblies to the GAC.  By deploying the DAL assemblies to the GAC, they can be used across web applications, and they will only need to be updated in a single place.

Information on how to deploy to the GAC and other considerations can be found on MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: the global assembly cache is shared storage for assemblies on a windows system.  you can install assemblies into it, and use them across applications.  more information on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: I _know_ what the GAC is! I meant please elaborate in your answer!

Comment: is this faster than Wcf tcp binding if I have both Tcp and website on same machine? on the other hand, how can do I use code from that GAC? Is it like shared class or something. thanks.

Comment: yes, the assemblies get referenced by the websites at design time, and loaded into the web applications app domain.  you won't deploy the service layer assemblies with the web application.